# URI SyntaxException

Tags: apache-camel

I am getting `URISyntaxException` on the following line in my xml file:

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${com.silever.camelProject.activemq.brokerUrl}
```

Here's the piece of code where I am using the above line:

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${com.silever.camelProject.activemq.brokerUrl}"/>
</bean>
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with that line ?

Comment: I don't use Java, but I'm pretty sure the problem is with the URI, not with the code.

Comment: What do you suggest ?

Comment: You should post more details, like the whole function where the error occurs.

Comment: @Barmar, please check now.

Comment: I still don't know Java. I don't know what `${...}` is supposed to be.

Comment: That's a placeholder whose value is in some property file. The problem is that the placeholder has syntax error. And that's what I need ot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly loading the URL string from the XML file, without parsing the `${...}` expression. The URI evaluator cannot do this.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: I usually don't work with XMLs, but I would try to find an API that resolves the `${...}` expression for you. If you can't find one, try to write your own.